# The root filesystem on /dev/sda5 requires a manual fsck

Tags: boot, fsck

It's showing this every time.

```
(i.e., without -a or -p options)   
fsck exited with status code 4  
The root filesystem on /dev/sda5 requires a manual fsck.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This indicates that a manual file system check should be done of your partition /dev/sda1. To attempt that, give the command

```
fsck -y /dev/sda1
```

then reboot with the `reboot` command.

Chances are it won't work. That a manual check is required points to pretty bad damage of the file system. Even if the file system can be returned to a consistent state, there is no certainty that no files have been damaged or are missing. Reformatting the partition and reinstalling the system is the only certain recovery option from this issue.

Comment: it actually says `/dev/sda5` I think?